# ListUI cells break down swiftUI?

Tags: ios, xcode, list, swiftui, pull-to-refresh

Faced with a problem where listUI falls apart sometimes. I call the get method when pull to refresh and the cells fall apart. And the older the phone the more often this happens and the better the less often. What can I do?

[image]

```
var body: some View {
    
    
    List {
         VStack {
            Color.clear.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 0) 

            if (self.emptyListMain == false) {
                ForEach(self.data, id: \.self.id) { item in
                VotesRowController(votes: item, showVotes: true, getVotesMenu: self.getVotes)
                }
            }
                
            else {
                VStack {
                    Text("Нет актуальных вопросов")
                }
            }
            
        }
        
           .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            
        }
    

    
    .pullToRefresh(isShowing: $isShowing) {
        expiredTimeArray.removeAll()
        print(self.isShowing)
            SwiftSpinner.show(duration: 1.5, title: "Загрузка...")
            self.isShowing = false
            self.getVotes()
      
    }
```

**P.S. SwiftUIRefresh - pod pull-to-refresh**

**P.S.2. Changed the pod - the problem remains**

Comment: This is a question to SwiftUIRefresh package owner.

Comment: @Asperi idk, but I have now changed the pod and the problem still hasn't gone away